# Netlogo, Prioritizing which agent to be searched first

Tags: netlogo

I have model which consists of two type of agents rescue-agents and population-agents. The model is basically a search and rescue where there are bunch of nodes connected with links.The rescue agents will first search for an agent to be rescued, then travel from node to node till they reach the population agent. 
Lets say my population-agents-own a variable called injury level, which takes values 1,2 or 3. I want my rescue-agents to first rescue population-agents with injury- level 2 or 3. Doesn't matter which one it is. Next move on to injury-level 1. 
The way I have written the code is, if the count of my population-agents with injury level 2 and 3 becomes 0. Start searching for agents with injury-level 1. But the problem is, as my population agents with injury level 2 or 3 closes to 0 (1 or 2 left), some of my rescue agents will remain at the same node without looking for agent of injury level 1, until all agents with injury 2 or 3 are rescued. 
For example if there were 2 rescue-agents, 1 pop-agent with injury-level 3 and 2 pop-agents with injury level 1. One of the rescue agent will travel to the pop-agent with injury 3. but the other will remain in the same node, until all  pop-agents with injury 3 are rescued and then he will starting to move on to injury 1.
Note each rescue agent will only target one population agent, to make sure they don't travel to the same person.
Is there any way to solve this problem where rescue agent are not waiting in same node until the population of injury 2 and 3 reaches 0? or better way of solving
Thanks

```
breed[rescue-agents rescue-agent]
breed[pop-agents pop-agent]
pop-agents-own [injury]
rescue-agents-own [target-pop-agent]

...
to go
...
;search agent

to find-agents
let pop-ij1 pop-agents with [injury = 1]
let pop-ij2 pop-agents with [injury = 2]
let pop-ij3 pop-agents with [injury = 3]
let Pop-ij2&3 pop-agents with [injury = 2 or injury = 3]

if target-pop-agent = nobody[
ifelse (count pop-ij2 = 0 and count pop-ij3 = 0)
[set target-pop-agent min-one-of (pop-ij1) in-radius 30 with [not 
targeted?][distance myself]]
[set target-pop-agent min-one-of (pop-ij2&3) in-radius 30 with [not 
targeted?][distance myself]]
]
...
end
```